# Bloquear opciones de un menu hasta que se seleciones una opcion especifica

Tags: java, menu, vectores

Tengo un menu con varias opciones para llenar un vector, y luego mostrar datos de dicho vector:

1. A.Llenar vector
2. B.Mostrar todos los números impares
3. C.Mostrar todos los números pares
4. D.Mostrar Ordenado de mayor a menor
5. E.Mostrar Ordenado de menor a mayor
6. F.Ver Contenido.
7. G.Mostrar el calculo o promedio de los números de vector
8. H.Ver Contenido inversa.
9. I.Salir

Pero necesito bloquear todas las opciones si la opcion A no se ha seleccionado. Pense en utilizar un do while, pero no se me ocurre como expresarlo en codigo

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author danio
 */
public class MenuOperador {

    private MetodosVector metodos;

    public MenuOperador() {
        this.metodos = new MetodosVector();
    }

    public void MostrarMenu() {
        String opcionesMenu = "***Vector numerico***\n";
        opcionesMenu += "A.Llenar vector\n";
        opcionesMenu += "B.Mostrar todos los números impares\n";
        opcionesMenu += "C.Mostrar todos los números pares\n";
        opcionesMenu += "D.Mostrar Ordenado de mayor a menor\n";
        opcionesMenu += "E.Mostrar Ordenado de menor a mayor\n";
        opcionesMenu += "F.Ver Contenido.\n";
        opcionesMenu += "G.Mostrar el calculo o promedio de los números de vector\n";
        opcionesMenu += "H.Ver Contenido inversa.\n";
        opcionesMenu += "I.Salir\n";
        opcionesMenu += "Ingrese una opcion una opción";
        String dato = "";
        boolean opcionA= false;
        

        do {
            dato = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(opcionesMenu);

            switch (dato) {

                case "A":
                    this.metodos.llenarPorUsuario();
                    break;
                
                case "B":
                    this.metodos.mostrarNumerosImpares();
                    break;

                case "C":
                    this.metodos.mostrarNumerosPares();
                    break;
                case "D":
                    this.metodos.AcomodarMayorAmenor();
                    break;
                case "E":
                    this.metodos.AcomodarMenorAmayor();
                    break;
                case "F":
                    this.metodos.mostrarVectorOG();
                    break;
                case "G":
                    this.metodos.promedioNumeros();
                    break;
                case "H":
                    this.metodos.mostrarVectorInversa();
                    break;
                case "I":
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fin del programa");
                    break;
            }

        } while (!dato.equals("I"));
    }

}
```

Comment: que es MetodosVector?

Comment: Es la clase principal donde manejo todos los metodos que el menu esta llamando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero define a nivel de clase tu variable boolean `opcionA` para determinar que la opción "A" fue seleccionada.

Después agrega un bloque en el cual verifiques el valor de `opcionA` y si la opción "A" no fue seleccionada, de otra forma te permite seleccionar la opción.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author danio
 */
public class MenuOperador {

    private MetodosVector metodos;
    boolean opcionA= false;

    public MenuOperador() {
        this.metodos = new MetodosVector();
    }

    public void MostrarMenu() {
        String opcionesMenu = "***Vector numerico***\n";
        opcionesMenu += "A.Llenar vector\n";
        opcionesMenu += "B.Mostrar todos los números impares\n";
        opcionesMenu += "C.Mostrar todos los números pares\n";
        opcionesMenu += "D.Mostrar Ordenado de mayor a menor\n";
        opcionesMenu += "E.Mostrar Ordenado de menor a mayor\n";
        opcionesMenu += "F.Ver Contenido.\n";
        opcionesMenu += "G.Mostrar el calculo o promedio de los números de vector\n";
        opcionesMenu += "H.Ver Contenido inversa.\n";
        opcionesMenu += "I.Salir\n";
        opcionesMenu += "Ingrese una opcion una opción";
        String dato = "";
        //boolean opcionA= false;
        

        do {
            dato = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(opcionesMenu);

            /*---------------------------------------*/
            if(opcionA == false && !dato.equals("A")){ //Si opcionA es false y la opción es diferente a "A", muestra mensaje
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Primero debe seleccionar la opción A.");                
                return;
            }else{
                opcionA = true;
            }
            /*---------------------------------------*/

            switch (dato) {

                case "A":
                    this.metodos.llenarPorUsuario();
                    break;
                
                case "B":
                    this.metodos.mostrarNumerosImpares();
                    break;

                case "C":
                    this.metodos.mostrarNumerosPares();
                    break;
                case "D":
                    this.metodos.AcomodarMayorAmenor();
                    break;
                case "E":
                    this.metodos.AcomodarMenorAmayor();
                    break;
                case "F":
                    this.metodos.mostrarVectorOG();
                    break;
                case "G":
                    this.metodos.promedioNumeros();
                    break;
                case "H":
                    this.metodos.mostrarVectorInversa();
                    break;
                case "I":
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fin del programa");
                    break;
            }

        } while (!dato.equals("I"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, amigo, funciono perfecto!